# Odd JavaScript Syntax that looks like a Python tuple

Tags: javascript, syntax, d3.js

I'm doing some work with D3.js and am looking at tweaking a version of one of the built-in mapping projections. I'm looking through the source code and have found the function definition below which uses a syntax I'm not familiar with:

```
function albersUsa(coordinates) {
  var x = coordinates[0], y = coordinates[1];
  point = null;
  (lower48Point(x, y), point) || (alaskaPoint(x, y), point) || hawaiiPoint(x, y);
  return point;
}
```

Specifically, how is `(lower48Point(x, y), point) || (alaskaPoint(x, y), point) || hawaiiPoint(x, y);` evaluated?

If you need more context, this example occurs at line 3257 of the D3 source, which can be found here: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's shorthand for

```
lower48point(x, y);
if (!point) {
  alaskaPoint(x, y);
  if (!point) {
    hawaiiPoint(x, y);
  }
}
```

The three functions must alter the value of the relatively-global variable "point".  The `||` version uses comma operators to carry out two expressions and exploits the side-effects.

Personally I would not feel good about myself for writing that code.

Comment: Note in particular that `point` is set inside the function calls, not returned.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Each `if` statement should be evaluating not only point, but also the result of `lower48point`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes, though looking at that code I have no clue how it happens. That code makes me even more afraid of d3.

Comment: @Langdon the value of `(expr1, expr2)` is just the value of `expr2`.  In my code, the functions are clearly being called. I suppose I could have use the `,` operator in the `if` test but I was trying to be as clear as possible about what's going on.

Comment: @Pointy I guess you're making the assumption that `point` is being altered.  With the original code, if `lower48point` returns false but point becomes true, `alaskaPoint` will not be called.

Comment: @Langdon and the exact same thing happens in my code; it really truly is equivalent.  If calling `lower48point()` causes `point` to become non-null, then that `if` statement body won't be evaluated. The return values from those function calls are not used in either version.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the persistence and clarification... I was getting myself confused in Chrome console.

Comment: @Pointy `point` is set in the definition of `pointStream`, which is used in the projections. I completely agree that this code isn't particularly nice though -- guess somebody wanted to show off ;)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff ah, OK.  I figured it had to be something like that; the code was making me dizzy so I just stopped looking after a little while :)

Answer (score 2):

`||` in JavaScript is the fallback operator.  A simple example is:

```
var a = true || 1; // evaluates to true
var a = false || 1; // evaluates to 1
var a = 'x' || 1; // evaluates to true
```

If the left side evaluates to a *truthy* value, the result is the left side and the right side is not evaluated.  You can extend it further as they did here by passing in a list of arguments in parenthesis.  In this case, if each item on the left evaluates to truthy, the right side will not be evaluated.  And as you can see, you can chain as many of these statements together as you like.